# Radio Button Logic - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to add logic to a set of radio buttons:

Using JavaScript, rework the registration form so that users aren’t able to sign up for workshops in combinations that are invalid.

Here are the rules:

Day 1

Session 1

Workshop A

Workshop B – covers session 1 and session 2, therefore if someone selects B, no workshops in session 2 may be chosen.

Workshop C

Session 2

Workshop D

Workshop E

Workshop F – if they take F, they must also take H. (Not G or I)

Day 2

Session 3

Workshop G

Workshop H –cannot take H unless they signed up for F

Workshop I

Note: If the user selects Workshop B, not only should they not be able to select any Session 2 workshops, but also Workshop H is an invalid choice.

```html
<fieldset>
<legend><b>Workshop Registration</b></legend>
<br>

<label for="CSV"><b>Session 1 - Advanced Horror</b></label>
<br>
<fieldset id="group1">
<input type="radio" id="A" value="1" name="group1" required /><label for="A">The Nature of Horror: What Scares Us and Why</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="B" value="1" name="group1"/><label for="B">Writing Scary: Techniques for Maximum Horror Effect</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="C" value="1" name="group1"/><label for="C">Monsters: The Things that Go Bump in the Night</label>
<br>
</fieldset>
<br>

<label for="CSV"><b>Session 2 - Sci-Fi and Fantasy</b></label>
<br>
<fieldset id="group2">
<input type="radio" id="D" value="1" name="group2" required /><label for="D">Kick Your Scene Into Action</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="E" value="1" name="group2"/><label for="E">Naming People and Places</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="F" value="1" name="group2"/><label for="F">Dystopia Now!</label>
<br>
</fieldset>
<br>

<label for="CSV"><b>Session 3 - Mystery and Thriller</b></label>
<br>
<fieldset id="group3">
<input type="radio" id="G" value="1" name="group3" required /><label for="G">Writing the Mystery Series</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="H" value="1" name="group3"/><label for="H">Plotting a Thriller</label>
<br>
<input type="radio" id="I" value="1" name="group3"/><label for="I">Six Steps to Writing Unputdownable Suspense</label>
<br>
</fieldset>
<br>
<div></div>
</fieldset>
```

I'm new to this so not sure how to even begin with JavaScript. Can anyone help me get in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow :). Have you already tried something?

Comment: Thank you! I have not tried anything yet. I know I will need to use the id values of each radio button but not sure how JavaScript works.

Comment: To get help on this site, you need to show us something we can work with, e. g. an attempt of solving your problem. As you didn't try anything yet, you will need to do so and add this attempt to your question. If you don't know where to start, look for a JavaScript course / tutorial. Your requirements are covered at the beginning of probably most JavaScript courses. You can start here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp and here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/First_steps (dives deeper into the topic). Good luck!